# Creating a simple instance of ExoPlayer

Tags: android, streaming, mp3, exoplayer

I am currently looking to develop an application that utilises Dash through the ExoPlayer in Android.

To begin with I am going through the demo project however am having trouble with even creating a simple working instance of ExoPlayer that can stream mp3 or similar.

Would really appreciate any help anyone can give relating to getting a very simple exoplayer instance working from which i can adapt and build upon or if anyone has any leads for more references or guides which I can follow as there seems to be very little documentation available.

Thanks very much for all and any help!

Answer (score 20):

First of all instantiate your ExoPlayer with this line:

```
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT, minBufferMs, minRebufferMs);
```

If you want to play audio only you can use these values:

```
RENDERER_COUNT = 1 //since you want to render simple audio
minBufferMs = 1000 
minRebufferMs = 5000
```

Both buffer values can be tweaked according to your requirements

Now you have to create a DataSource. When you want to stream mp3 you can use the DefaultUriDataSource. You have to pass the Context and a UserAgent. To keep it simple play a local file and pass null as userAgent:

```
DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, null);
```

Then create the sampleSource:

```
ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
                    uri, dataSource, new Mp3Extractor(), RENDERER_COUNT, requestedBufferSize);
```

uri points to your file, as an Extractor you can use a simple default Mp3Extractor if you want to play mp3. requestedBufferSize can be tweaked again according to your requirements. Use 5000 for example.

Now you can create your audio track renderer using the sample source as follows:

```
MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);
```

Finally call prepare on your exoPlayer instance:

```
exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
```

To start playback call:

```
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, Exoplayer is in my opinion a great asset for android however at the moment it is woefully under represented in beginner friendly documentation, though perhaps beginners should stay away till they know better eh! I have another question I just asked related to the player which I would love some input on if you feel you could help with that also!

thanks!

Comment: Super, but how to you show the video? With VideoView? .. Nevermind, just found https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/

Comment: @MaxMarshall and mismor How can I play an aac file? What should be the Extractor then?

Answer (score 10):

Here is how you would do it using the new ExoPlayer 2 API, and the `SimpleExoPlayer`.

First create the player:

```
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, bandwidthMeter);

TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, loadControl);

player.addListener(...); // To receive events from the player
```

Then create your `MediaSource`. For MP3 you can use `ExtractorMediaSource`:

```
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(mp3UriString);
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, mainHandler, mediaSourceListener); // Listener defined elsewhere
```

Then prepare and play when ready:

```
player.prepare(mediaSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

For DASH you would use [DashMediaSource](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/dash/DashMediaSource.html) instead of `ExtractorMediaSource`.

Comment: **Update**:                                                                              
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeter)

Comment: this has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Today while working on a project, I found that `this.myExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getActivity());` and some others are now deprecated and Android studio suggested to use new way. So I did a quick Google for it but everywhere I found the old way. So I looked into the `SimpleExoPlayer.java` file, read some methods. So this is how you initialize simpleExoPlayer:

```java
  Activity activity = getActivity(); // if you are in a fragment
  // Or,   activity = YourActivity.this;      if you are in an Activity
  SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(activity).build();
```

I hope this is helpful.