# How to stream mp3 url using exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

Exoplayer library seems so complex for me. Can anyone help me how to stream radio station url using exoplayer library? I tried with MediaPlayer , it works fine but it took so much time to prepare. Here is what I tried.

```
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT);

    Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
    DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(getApplicationContext(), null, userAgent);
    Mp3Extractor extractor = new Mp3Extractor();
    ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
            uri, dataSource, extractor, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
     MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);
    exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);

    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

I don't understand how to get userAgent and what is meaning of it?

Comment: @user1438038 I added my code

Comment: Is your app crashing or what is the exact problem? If so, can you provide logs? I've answered your question regarding the user agent, but I'm not sure if this will solve the problems you are facing, because it sounds like there is some other issue.

Comment: See my answer in this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43722033

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a nice description of what a user agent is:
[user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)
Also here the definition of how a user agent should look like:
[structure of user agent header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3)
Here you can see how your browser's user agent looks like:
http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

To put it simply you can create your user agent like this:

"YourAppName/VersionCode"

Finally a description of how to use ExoPlayer to stream mp3:
[Stream mp3 with ExoPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048475/creating-a-simple-instance-of-exoplayer/31515417#31515417)
In this example it is a local mp3 though, but the only difference should be the url of the mp3 and the missing user agent.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to stream m3u8 files using ExoPlayer Lib.
check this code and don't forget to change the URL to yours and also change the content type as the blew code
hope to help 
https://github.com/karim23/SimpleStreamPlayer/tree/master

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //change the live streaming URL with yours. 
    contentUri = /*"Your mp3 URL.."*/;
    // contentType = DemoUtil.TYPE_MP3;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class).setData(Uri.parse(contentUri))
            .putExtra(VideoPlayerActivity.CONTENT_ID_EXTRA, -1)
            //Change the type according to the live streaming extension.
            .putExtra(VideoPlayerActivity.CONTENT_TYPE_EXTRA, DemoUtil.TYPE_MP3);
    liveStreamingTv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_liveStreamingTv);
    liveStreamingTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with codec, exoPlayer doesn't support aac+

Comment: I think it supports aac. I am able to play the aac files using ExoPlayer. But I somehow am not able to getDuration()