# How can I adapt a Firebase Storage URL for Exoplayer?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, audio-streaming, exoplayer

I'm trying to stream audios from Firebase Storage and I use Exoplayer to play the audios. But as far as I understand, Exoplayer does not support the Storage downloadUrls and I get exception.

## Question:

Can I adapt the URLs to Exoplayer? Is there a way to do this?

Sample URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/........appspot.com/o/........%2Falways.mp3?alt=media&token=23881b5b-81af-48d1-80cb-4adb8672cc6d

## Code:

```
 FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
        StorageReference kelimeler = storageRef.child("filesPath");


 player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext());
 PlayerView playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.player_view);
 playerView.setPlayer(player);

 DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(),
                Util.getUserAgent(getContext(),  "appName"));



kelimeler.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
               
      MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);

      player.prepare(mediaSource);
      player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }
        });
```

## Exception:

> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor) could read the stream.

```
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:973)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:891)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:379)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43722033/549372) seems related. `Firebase Storage` does not matter much, because it's `Uri`. `dataSourceFactory` might be `null` within that scope.

Comment: The error message you're seeing says something about the type of content stored in Cloud Storage.  A URL is just a generic locator for data.  It could locate any piece of data.  You'll have to make sure the file pointed to by the URL is supported by ExoPlayer.